# Crear un match query en 2 tablas con elasticsearch 2.3

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7

Como puedo hacer una consulta entre 2 tablas, tengo las siguientes tablas

```
Company:
- id
- name
- domain
- timestamp

Target
- id
- name
- domain
- company
- website
- company_id
- timestamp

User
- id
- firstName
- lastName
- email
- company_id
-timestamp
```

Necesito hacer un match entre domain de target y el correo del usuario que pertenezcan a la compañia.

Estoy trabajando la ElasticSearch 2.3 con la libreria elasticsearch-py con python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

Desafortunadamente no se puede hacer lo que quieres en elasticsearch, para solventar el problema tienes que indexar la información dentro del mismo indice como documentos anidados (nested documents)